# Deploy a nodejs project in Microsoft Azure containing backend only

Tags: node.js, azure, server, backend

I am developing a angular project with node js as backend. In the backend microservices are used. Frontend and backend are seperate projects. I am trying to deploy both in azure. I was able to deploy the front end properly. I tried to deploy the backend too. But it was not successful. Does anyone know how to deploy a node js project with backend only in azure ?

**UPDATE**: 
The thing is that I don't have a dist folder to build the node project. It just contains a server with microservices. What we do is we will use npm start to run it. When I try to hit the backend from the frontend, I get an saying that "You don't have the permission to view the directory or page".

Comment: I've used this link https://dev.to/bashirk/the-painless-way-to-deploying-your-nodejs-app-on-azure-part-2-5151

Comment: What problems have you encountered in deploying the node backend service program? Did the deployment succeed and the service did not start?

Comment: In your local environment, you use cmd to enter the project folder, such as `D: \ MyProject`, and then you can start the project with npm start. Then you copy all the files in the MyProject directory to app services and upload them using FTP. Upload to the wwwroot directory in kudu, at this time the directory `D:\home\site\wwwroot` and the local`D:\MyProject` are equivalent. Then in kudu, `cd D:\home\site\wwwroot` then npm start to test whether you can start your project.

Comment: I provided some ideas for handling the problem in the answers and comments, if you need further help, please let me know.